# FormGroup validator disable to enable

Tags: angular

I am trying to enable textbox which is disabled by formControl.

**this is typescript code**

```
Name = new FormControl({ value:'', disabled: true }, [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(10) ]);
```

**HTML**

```
  <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="Name">
```

I want to disabled false (enable texbox) on dropdown change please give an answer.
Only enable code (how change disabled prop to false).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Name.enable()
```

You should really dive into some documentation, AbstractControl methods for example.
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/AbstractControl-class.html